# How to return an object in a method with onDataChange?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to firebase. I have a method which returns a driver object retrieved from a firebase database. Please help me.

I did research and found that the problem is that onDataChange() is asynchronous so it is called last. So I tried to put the final return statement in the onDataChange(). This made an error: "cannot return a value from a method of void result type". Some solution suggested to save the return type in a variable and return it at the end, but this solution was for primitive data types which is not my case.

```
private Driver getOneAvailableDriver(String driverUid) {
        //get the driver's uid code in the available drivers node
        final DatabaseReference driverUidRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(getString(R.string.drivers_available))
                .child(driverUid);

        final Driver driver = new Driver();
        //get the driver's track
        driverUidRef.child(getString(R.string.track)).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String track = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                driver.setTrack(track);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
        //get the driver's location
        DatabaseReference locationRef = driverUidRef.child("l");
        locationRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                ArrayList<Double> customLocation = (ArrayList<Double>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                LatLng location = new LatLng(customLocation.get(0), customLocation.get(1));
                driver.setLocation(location);

                Log.i("getOneAvailableDriver", driver.toString());
                return driver; //here where I tried the second time
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        Log.i("getOneAvailableDriver", driver.toString());
        return driver;
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you need to return something ?

Comment: Yes. I'll need the returned value in other methods

Comment: It is void method, so you can't return value. Where you want the value returned to ?

Comment: I want this method getOneAvailableDriver() to return the Driver object. I'll use it later for adding Driver objects to an ArrayList.

Comment: You already return the driver at the last line, no ?

Comment: The last return line returns null. I have read that this is because onDataChange() is an asynchronous method.

Comment: how about add a method  inside onDataChange() and pass the driver object to that method?

Comment: What should I do in that method?

Comment: what you want to do when the return value is back ?

Comment: I want it to be saved in a variable to be added later in an ArrayList

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191788/discussion-between-john-joe-and-noussa).

Answer (score 0):

> This made an error: "cannot return a value from a method of void
>   result type".

You can't return any value since the type is void.

**Edit**

You may create a method inside `onDataChange()` and pass the driver object as parameter.

```
Log.i("getOneAvailableDriver", driver.toString());
myMethod(driver) // add new function here
return driver; //here where I tried the second time
```

If you want to know more, you can refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47847694/how-to-return-datasnapshot-value-as-a-result-of-a-method)

Comment: This is just a small error while I was writing the question. I have edited it.